# Order rows based on part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table that has a column of addresses. To be used in a report, I need to sort the data by location i.e. N, NW, S, SE, W and divider street called State. These are not always at the end of the field.

```
SELECT 
  Event.EventID, 
  Event.EventDateTime, 
  SUBSTRING(RIGHT(RTRIM(Event.Location),2), 1, 2) AS Loc, 
  Event.Location 
FROM Event AS Event 
WHERE Event.EventDateTime BETWEEN '12/11/2014' AND '12/12/2014' 
AND Event.Location LIKE '% NW %' 
ORDER BY Event.EventDateTime
```

This will give me

> ALTIMONT DR NW & CASCADE DR NW

but I also need to get

> 5765 COMMERCIAL ST SE STE 170, SUBWAY SANDWICHES

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and the sort order you want.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant parts of your database schema. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated the original post.

Comment: What platform are you using? (Mysql, SQL Server, Oracle...etc)

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Here is a way to simulate DDL (data definition language) and some inserts.  Add some of your example rows and expected results.


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EventHolder') IS NOT NULL
begin
 drop table #EventHolder
end


CREATE TABLE #EventHolder
(EventID INT , EventDateTime datetime , Location varchar(128) )
   

/* simulate your insert */
INSERT INTO #EventHolder (EventID, EventDateTime , Location) 
select 1 , '01/01/2001', 'Main St' union all select 2 , '02/02/2002', 'Elm St' 

Select * from #EventHolder


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EventHolder') IS NOT NULL
begin
 drop table #EventHolder
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current criteria, you just need an `OR`.

```
WHERE Event.EventDateTime BETWEEN '12/11/2014' AND '12/12/2014' 
AND (Event.Location LIKE '% NW %' 
  OR Event.Location LIKE '% SE %'  
  OR Event.Location LIKE '% S %' 
  OR Event.Location LIKE '% W %')
ORDER BY Event.EventDateTime
```

Note the parenthesis to group the `OR` clauses in one.

Additionally, a simple case statement can get you the direction regardless of location:

```
SELECT 
  Event.EventID, 
  Event.EventDateTime, 
  case when CHARINDEX (' NW ', event.location) > 0 
       then SUBSTRING(Event.Location, CHARINDEX (' NW ', event.location) + 1, 2) 
       when CHARINDEX (' SE ', event.location) > 0 
       then SUBSTRING(Event.Location, CHARINDEX (' SE ', event.location) + 1, 2)
       when CHARINDEX (' S ', event.location) > 0 
       then SUBSTRING(Event.Location, CHARINDEX (' S ', event.location) + 1, 1)
       when CHARINDEX (' W ', event.location) > 0 
       then SUBSTRING(Event.Location, CHARINDEX (' W ', event.location) + 1, 1)
  end AS Loc, 
  Event.Location 
FROM Event AS Event WHERE Event.EventDateTime BETWEEN '12/11/2014' AND '12/12/2014' 
AND (Event.Location LIKE '% NW %' 
  OR Event.Location LIKE '% SE %'  
  OR Event.Location LIKE '% S %' 
  OR Event.Location LIKE '% W %')
ORDER BY Event.EventDateTime
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32f93/12)

SQL Server doesnt have native regex grouping or this could be simplified.